# How to access on-premises webservice from within an azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, azure-function-app

We have a service Fabric Solution which connects to an on-premises web service. Calling the web service is not a problem for the Service Fabric solution. All works fine.

We had to extract functionality from the SF solution and convert it into an Azure Function.

The problem is that the Azure Function cannot connect to the on-prem webservice. This is the error we receive:

> "Error while calling .... api: A connection attempt failed because the
> connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
> established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond."

Current setup:

- An azure VNET "vnetA" which contains the following subnets:

  - subA 10.0.1.128/25 which is a Virtual Network Gateway with a site to site (IPsec) connection. For the on-prem webservice I presume.
  - subB 10.0.1.0/25 which is a subnet used by the Service Fabric solution.
  - subC 10.0.2.0/25 which is a subnet used by the Function App which contains the Azure function.
- Function App/Azure Function connected to vnetA and subnet subC (10.0.2.0/25) Plan type: App service plan - Standard S1, it has no proxies defined.
- An Api Management Service to connect to the SF solution and the Azure Function. (If we bypass this and use the function url the error is the same.)
- Subnet subA has following settings:

  - NAT-gateway: None
  - Route table: None
  - Services: none selected
  - Delegate subnet to the service: None
  - Network Security group: None
- Subnet subC has following settings:

  - NAT-gateway: None
  - Route table: None
  - Services: none selected
  - Delegate subnet to the service: Microsoft.Web/ServerFarms
  - Network Security group: nsgA

Network security group settings:
[image: nsg]

The person who set up the azure network is not working for us anymore. What do I need to do to get this to work? I'm a developer and have never worked on (Azure) networks before so this is way out of my comfort zone and I can't seem to find/understand anything on the internet.

**Update:**
It seems an azure function cannot access on-prem resources without the use of an ASE (Azure app Service Environment) which has a base price of 1000+$ a month. So i'm going to have to look for some kind of workaround.

Comment: can u check the network rules between sub A and C to see if traffic is being allowed ? and did you do the vnet integration and proxy setup in the function correctly?

Comment: @Aravind I updated my question with the information you requested. No proxies are defined for the azure function.

Comment: ok proxy is not mandatory but it is used in cases where you need to forward requests to a resource inside a vnet.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that concerned me here is the "Plan type: Standard". Do you mean by this "Consumption (Serverless)"? If yes, this might be an issue - Regional VNET integration is only available for the "Premium" (consumption) plan.

Or do you have it under the regular "Standard" App Service Plan? It this case I would ask (given that whoever deployed it in the first place is no longer in your org), how old is the function. Following the official docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration):

> The feature is available only from newer Azure App Service scale
> units that support PremiumV2 App Service plans. Note that this does
> not mean your app must run on a PremiumV2 pricing tier, only that it
> must run on an App Service Plan where the PremiumV2 option is
> available (which implies that it is a newer scale unit where this VNet
> integration feature is then also available).

If the above is all OK, I would also consider DNS - how are you calling the on-premises web service? Are you using an FQDN? If yes, can the Function App resolve the name?

I would suggest that you use the App Service Console to check connectivity. Please be mindful that do to the sandbox limitations you cannot use nslookup and ping commandline tools. Instead MSFT gives you nameresolver and tcpping. For reference see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHTu9.png) picture.

Comment: The plan type is: App Service Plan - Standard S1

Comment: the on-prem services are called with an ip address so resolving is not the issue.
Using the console to check connectivity returns a connection timeout.

Comment: Ay firewall on the on-premises side, perhaps?

Also, is your subnet C a new subnet? If it wasn't present when the VPN tunnel was configured, it might be the case that you're missing a route on-premises. In such a case, the device which terminates the tunnel on your side simply doesn't know that the next-hop for 10.0.2.0/25 is on the other side of the tunnel. The request coming from the Function reaches the web service, but the response isn't routed correctly.

That wouldn't be a problem if you have BGP enabled, but it's a relatively new feature for VPN in Azure, so I'd expect static routes

Comment: Subnet C is indeed a new subnet. The timeout occurs after 21 seconds and in the docs you linked to it says that this may be caused because of a firewall so you might be right. I'll contact the service owner tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly it is impossible to access on-prem resources from within an Azure function without using an ASE (Azure App Service Environment) The problem is that this will set you back about 1000$ a month.

To overcome this issue we opted to run the azure function inside a container, inside a kubernetes cluster. A lot of overhead but not as expensive...

Comment: Do you have a link to official docs that state this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro#:~:text=The%20ASE%20feature%20is%20a,Azure%20Resource%20Manager%20virtual%20network.&text=You%20can%20use%20the%20security,network%20communications%20for%20your%20apps. 
Under the title "Virtual network support"

Comment: Thank you, though this doc doesn't assert `"...it is impossible to access on-prem resources from within an Azure function without using an ASE..."` as you stated. I'm looking for something that says this. Otherwise, I'm still investigating how to do this without ASE.